# MVC pattern and model object initialization in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, model

If I am using an instance of `NSArray` to populate a pop-up button, where in terms of MVC does that `NSArray` need to be initialised? I'm guessing it would fall under Model, however if that's the case, how do I initialise the array? Do I start a new implementation file to contain the array? (Obviously don't want to use my app delegate file as that would fall under Controller, not Model.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "model" part of MVC is the data that the app stores, presents, and/or allows the user to manipulate. It would largely be the same whether your app was running on a Mac, an iPhone or whatever. The "view" is the UI. That is the things the user actually sees on screen. The controller is the part that goes in between these two. It's responsible for implementing the specific behavioral logic for the app as well as "gluing" the view layer to the model layer.

So, with that said, the array of items to be displayed in a popup button may or may not be part of the model. It entirely depends on the specific UI you're implementing. If the selection is between a number of objects represented in the model, the array's contents would indeed be part of the model, but it still might be that the controller pulls the items out of the model in another form and turns them into an NSArray. It might also be a way to select between e.g. a fixed list of actions to be performed, in which case it's more properly part of the controller layer itself.

In other words, there's no one answer to your question. But, the likelihood is that the controller will at least provide the array in question to the UI, and may also be entirely responsible for its content. It all depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, so I have a pop-up button that, dependant on what is chosen from the button, will drive the output of another object in my app. So far I've initialised my `NSArray` in a separate model file and will then call on that array via the app delegate controller. Is that the best way to perform this action, or am I over-complicating things by splitting the array from the app delegate?

Comment: It's still hard to tell exactly what you're doing without real specifics, but my hunch is that you're doing more work than you need to. There's probably no reason to create a class that does nothing more than contain and initialize NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization would happen within the model object, but that initialization would likely be called from a view controller (I wish these were just called controllers--there's no ModelController class.)  Possibly in viewDidLoad but really wherever the best fit for your use case would require.

Comment: Not all controllers are view controllers. NSDocument is essentially a model controller. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The model object should initialised by the controller object, usually in the `viewDidLoad` method. If a model object is owned by another model object (for example, if your custom model object has an `NSArray` instance variable, then your custom object is the parent and the `NSArray` is the child), then that child model object should be initialised in the initialised method of the parent model object.

I suppose your `NSArray` is a model object on its own, so it should be initialised in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller object.

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't bother with a separate model object at all?

Comment: That totally depends on your application. An instance of `NSArray` is a model object on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one answer and not necessarily how everyone develop applications in objective C.

If I have an app with a small data model or with models scoped to their views, I will put the models on the AppDelegate or in the viewControllers themselves, if they are limited in scope to that view.

They will be initialized closest to where it makes sense in the app for that data.

Sometimes you will see a "FAT" viewController which represents a home screen controller or main screen controller and folks will pile the models on that class.  Its very common.

But if I have an application with a large data model - lots of models that have lifetimes not scoped to the life of a view - then I will create a class in my application called *myAppNameHere*AppModel, and I will centralize the storage of application models, and use service classes as necessary to request data to populate/update models.

This is just one approach.  And great question!